# How to remove specific sequence of letters (different number each time) until specific letter

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a problem with transforming strings like these:

```
"xxx / yyy / zzz / aaa /  /  /  /  /  /"
"bbb / ttt / kkk /  /  /  /  /  /  /"
"xxx / www / uuu / aaa / ccc /  /  /  /  /"
```

to these:

```
"xxx / yyy / zzz / aaa"
"bbb / ttt / kkk"
"xxx / www / uuu / aaa / ccc"
```

I achieved that with below loop:

```
string tree = "xxx / yyy / zzz / aaa /  /  /  /  /  /";

for (int i = tree.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   if (tree[i] != '/' && tree[i] != ' ')
   {
      tree = tree.Substring(0, i + 1);
      break;
   }
}
```

But I believe there is more efficient way to do that for thousands of records, best without loop...

Comment: Any way you do this is going to require searching through each string here in some way. You might be able to speed it up by using e.g. `LastIndexOf("/  /")`, which the runtime will vectorise (at least on .NET Core)

Comment: As always, do any work with your profiler to hand, so you can see what the performance issues are

Comment: Read up on regular expressions. You may achieve what you want by doing Regex.Replace. The regex you are probably looking for to match is \s*/\s* (unescaped), which should be replaced by " / ". See https://regexr.com/5sm75

Comment: .net 5: https://dotnetfiddle.net/C9mexT Not sure how that compedes against Regex, though.

Comment: @Fildor, I like the idea, but most probably the entries will not be empty, since there seem to be spaces in between the slashes

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea Hit "Run" - output was `xxx / yyy / zzz / aaa` ...

Comment: @Fildor Ah, I missed the TrimEntries option. Sure, that works. tbh, regex is probably too big of a hammer for this :) Your solution might be more efficient speed-wise, not sure about memory.

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea In this case, I wouldn't be too sure about speed nor mem. Too often I found my expectations about either of those wildly off from reality. I'd really set up a BenchmarkDotNet and run the horses. (And maybe come up with some other ideas as well).

Comment: @Shilliene What should happen in case of `"xxx / yyy / zzz / aaa /"` - keep unchanged or  `"xxx / yyy / zzz / aaa"` ?

Comment: Is it _always_ exactly 9 "/" and content - if exists - is always exactly 3 chars? If so, you probably can compute the place to cut from the string length in O(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use regex.
Like so:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"((\/  )+\/?)";
        string substitution = @"";
        string input = @"xxx / yyy / zzz / aaa /  /  /  /  /  /";            
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```

In most cases a regex for text search and replacement is the way to go

Comment: This regex pattern would fail if the number of whitespaces in between the slashes is not consistent.

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea you are right but in all the examples the spaces are the same so that is why i made the Regex to match

Comment: Which is reasonable, imho. Given the example set. But adapting to a "dynamic" number of whitespace shouldn't be that hard, neither.

Comment: Since the question is about performance, I'm not hugely convinced this will be quicker

Answer (score 1):

Crazy Idea: **Only applies if my assumptions drawn from example set are true!**

Ok, so the assumptions:

1. It's *always* 9 x "/"
2. If content, it's always 3 chars
3. "Compartments" are filled from left to right ( no `"aaa /  / bbb / ..."` )

Therefore:

```
"  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /" => len = 27 => 0 items => return string.Empty
"aaa /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /" => len = 29 => 1 items => return substr(0, 3)
"aaa / bbb /  /  /  /  /  /  /  /" => len = 32 => 2 items => return substr(0, 9)
...
```

So you can build a Dictionary<int,int> => [(27,0), (29, 3), (32, 9), ...]
to look up the length of the string to return ...

Haven't run the horses, but 1 x string.Length + 1 Lookup + 1 string.Substring(0, N) should *at least* be faster than looping.

Comment: I rather suspect your second assumption won't hold, sadly, but I like the idea

Comment: @canton7 That might be the case, yes. I also didn't benchmark so please take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the trailing characters are always a repeat of "space space slash", you can tweak the loop to increase the speed:

```
        string tree = "xxx / yyy / zzz / aaa /  /  /  /  /  /";

        for (int i = tree.Length - 3; i >= 0; i-=3)
        {
            if (tree[i] != '/' && tree[i] != ' ')
            {
                tree = tree.Substring(0, i + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The string can be split using whitespace and "/" while ignoring the empty strings. This generates a string array that can be iterated to get the required strings in any format.

```
char[] separators = new char[] { ' ', '/' };

string[] subs = tree.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var sub in subs)
{
   tree += sub + " / ";
}
```

Comment: Answer's are great. But for best practices, please provide an explanation. You only posting code makes the OP and future commers copy and paste your answer without understanding the logic behind the answer. Please provide an answer with some explanation. Thank You!